# Copying from one location to another

Tags: list, file, powershell, copy, directory

I have a need to copy a folder and it's contents from one location to another for about 100 users:

Currently I have only had to do it for one user every now and then and I have leveraged this command:

```
$from = "\\server1\users\tom\windows\favorites"

$to = "\\server1\users\tom\favorites"

Copy-Item $from $to -recurse
```

Now I have to copy for a bunch of users. I know I can use a text file with user names in something like

```
$server = 'server1'
$src = "\\server1\users"
$dst = "\\server1\users\data"

(Get-Content .\MyFile.txt) -split ';' | % {
  Copy-Item -Path "$src\$_" -Destination "$dst\" -Recurse
}
```

But it is copying all the users in my text fileand all there data from one location to the other when all I need is there favorites folder. Below is what I need to copy

```
\\server1\users\tom\windows\favorites
```

to

```
\\server1\users\tom\favorites
```

I have to do this for about a 100 people.

Any idea on how I can leverage a text file with names to go into each users named folder and grab there favorites and move it over to the new destination in there new favorites folder?

Comment: don't forget to add a tag for the programming language

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested but does adding "windows\favorits" to the src like this help?

```
(Get-Content .\MyFile.txt) -split ';' | % {
Copy-Item -Path "$src\$_\windows\favorites"  -Destination "$dst\" -Recurse
}
```